# Getting error with basic one-to-many mapping

Tags: java, hibernate

I am creating a simple example by following the hibernate documentation for [one-to-many unidirectional mapping](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch08.html#assoc-unidirectional-12m)

I have created `Person` entity and `Address` entity as follows:

`Person.java`

```
public class Person {
    private int id;
    private Set<Address> addresses = new HashSet<Address>();
    // Setters & Getters


    public void addAddress(Address address) {
        this.addresses.add(address);
    }
}
```

`Address.java`

```
public class Address {
    private int id;
    // Setters & Getters
}
```

Mapping file:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="Person">
        <id name="id" column="personId">
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <set name="addresses">
            <key column="personId" not-null="true" />
            <one-to-many class="Address" />
        </set>
    </class>

    <class name="Address">
        <id name="id" column="addressId">
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

My program to save person and address:

```
    Session session = getSession();
    session.getTransaction().begin();

    Person p = new Person();
    Address a = new Address();

    p.addAddress(a);

    session.save(a);
    session.save(p);
```

Executing this program is giving an exception as: `not-null property references a null or transient value : Address._Person.addressesBackref`

Complete stacktrace:

```
org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value : Address._Person.addressesBackref
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Nullability.checkNullability(Nullability.java:106)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.AbstractEntityInsertAction.nullifyTransientReferencesIfNotAlready(AbstractEntityInsertAction.java:132)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.AbstractEntityInsertAction.makeEntityManaged(AbstractEntityInsertAction.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:201)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:179)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:166)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:332)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:288)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:137)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:209)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:715)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:707)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:702)
```

Can you please help me in fixing the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At DB level, your `Address` table has a foreign key called `personId` with `Person` table. Also as per the hibernate mapping file the foreign key has `not-null` constraint.

As per your code you are trying to save `Address` entity first (which goes to `Address` table) then you are saving the `Person` entity. So when hiberate tries to save the `Address` entity it has to insert the column `personId` because it has `not-null` constraint, as there is no record in `Person` table so hibernate throws an exception as `Address._Person.addressesBackref`.

So to fix this issue:

**Solution 1:**

Save the `Person`first then try to save the `Address` entity like this:

```
Person p = new Person();
Address a = new Address();

p.addAddress(a);

session.save(p);
session.save(a);
```

**Solution 2**

Just remove the `not-null` constraint on the foreign key - `personId`

Answer (score 1):

Here it is clearly saying you are putting a null value for a property which is declared as a not null property.

You are directly setting the objects with out any values.So person id is setting null.But you configured it as a not null.Check it once.

Answer (score 0):

The Exception clearly explains that `Address` you are adding to `Person.addresses` is either null or transient (Not saved). You can try saving `Address` before adding it to the Person.addresses.

And you need to commit the transaction. Please try the following code.

```
 Session session = getSession();
 Transaction tx;
 try {
     tx = session.beginTransaction();
     //do some work
     Person p = new Person();
     Address a = new Address();

     session.save(a);
     p.addAddress(a);

     session.save(p);
     tx.commit();
 }
 catch (Exception e) {
     if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
     throw e;
 }
 finally {
     session.close();
 }
```

Comment: Also the exception is different and says `Address._Person.addressesBackref`, it is not clear where the `addressesBackref` is coming from.